# Send separate mail for each record on status change

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10

I am working in Odoo v10. I have created a leave summary page (tree view) which shows a list of leave requests. Each leave request has its own email id in database (i.e. user's email id who applied that leave request). Please see the image below.
So, I want that whenever I change the state of a record here then an email should be sent to that record's email address.

Let's say for example- when I change the 'state' of record whose name column is 'werty' from 'To Approve' to 'Approved' then an email should sent to email address attached to that record.

I just required code for a function which can be triggered when I change the status and that function should fetch the email of that record and send email on that.
I have written the code for sending email based on email. But that's just for a dummy hardcoded email. I required the email of that record whose status I am changing.

[image: this is my leave request page]

Here is my code:

```
@api.onchange('state')
def test_server_action(self):

    fromaddr = "admin123@gmail.com"
    toaddr = "yyy.gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "xyz")
    msg['Subject'] = "Leave Request Status"

    if (self.state == 'confirm'):
        body = "Your leave Request has been approved by Dept. Waiting for final approval from office."
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    if (self.state == 'forward'):
        body = "Your leave request is more than 15 days. It has been forwarded to higher authority for approval."
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    if (self.state == 'refuse'):
        body = "Your leave request has been refused. Contact your department."
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    if(self.state == 'pending'):
        body = "Your leave is in pending."
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    server.quit()
```

Comment: Do not use all caps in your titles, that is [considered shouting and rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting).

Comment: Have you checked `self` to see what variables the instance has? I'm guessing, all the information you need is in there or that you some how query the `api` variable for selected records.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, From next time I will keep that in mind. Thank you for correction.

Comment: @Torxed Thank you for the suggestion. The instance has all the variable I have defined in the model class. But how am I going to query the API variable based on selected record. I just need the email(inside my defined function) of that record whose state I am changing.